# Prevent redirect coming from external domains

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to prevent that an external domain make a redirect to my domain. I tried using the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.extenaldomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$  /my_error_page.htm [R,L]
```

but it doesn't work. I tried also:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_FORWARDED} ^http://www.extenaldomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$  /my_error_page.htm [R,L]
```

but it doesn't work too. any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: it works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} extenaldomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_error_page.htm
RewriteRule (.*)  /my_error_page.htm [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply precise the domain name without adding extra stuff?
Try this, it should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} extenaldomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  /my_error_page.htm [R,L]
```

---

Tell me if it does

Comment: Thank you, it works, but it generates a TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error... but I solved it, see my response